# Every topology for which every singleton subset is dense must be trivial

Tags: general-topology

The whole exercise is:

Prove that a topological space is equipped with the trivial topology if and only if every singleton subset is dense.

---

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a topological space equipped with the trivial topology  $\tau = ${$\emptyset,X$}, then the closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Let $A = ${$x_0$} with $x_0 \in X$. Since the only closed set containing $A$ is $X$, then we must have $\overline{A} = X$. So $A$ is dense in $X$.

---

$(\Leftarrow)$
To prove the topology is the trivial one, then we must prove that if $G \in \tau$, $G \neq \emptyset$, then $G=X$.

Since $G \neq \emptyset$, then there exists $x_0 \in G \subseteq X$. Let $A = ${$x_0$}$ \subseteq X$. Since $A$ is a singleton subset, then $\overline{A} = X$.

Also, there's this property: $\overline{\overline{A} \cap G} = \overline{A \cap G}$, which implies $\overline{G} = \overline{A}$ (note that $A \subseteq G$), then $\overline{G} = X$.

I don't know how to continue from here, or if there's another way. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove that the only nonempty closed set $G$ in $X$ is $X$ itself (if this is the case then the same will also go for open sets, since they are just the complements of the closed sets).

As you already reasoned, since $G$ is nonempty it includes a singleton $\{x\}$, whose closure will have to be $X$. To complete the proof you just need two more lemmas:

- The closure operator is increasing. So, since $\{x\} \subseteq G$, we have $\overline{\{x\}} \subseteq \overline{G}$ and hence $\overline{G} = X$.
- Since $G$ is closed, it is equal to its closure. Hence $G = X$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive instead: suppose that $\varnothing\ne G\ne X$, and find a singleton that is **not** dense in $X$. HINT: Let $x_0\in X\setminus G$, and let $A=\{x_0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial topology on a space $X$ can be written as $\{\emptyset, X\}$. We can also cleverly write this topology as $\{U \in \mathscr{P}(X)$ : $(\exists x \in X (x \in U)) \to U = X\}$.

In fact, the second definition is required if you're using constructive logic. But I digress.

We also note that a useful definition of "$A$ is dense" is the statement: for all open $U$, if $U$ has an element then $A \cap U$ has an element.

Suppose that every singleton subset of $X$ is dense. Now let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. Suppose we have some $x \in U$. Then consider an arbitrary $y \in X$. We see that $\{y\}$ is dense. And we see that $U$ is an open set, and $U$ has an element. So it must be the case that there is an element of $\{y\} \cap U$; that is, we must have $y \in U$. Then $U = X$.

This shows that $X$ has the trivial topology.